# issues with Ansible and vars precedence with dependencies

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm having issues with vars precedence, hope you can help me here.

I'm currently using geerlingguy.ansible-role-postgresql as a dependency of my own postgresql role. Is define as a dependency in meta and I'm using import_role on my main task.

I was using vars/main.yml on my own role to override the defaults but now I need to extend my own role a bit like defining diferent variables depending from which group is the server in the inventory.

For this I use group_vars but with the vars/main.yml hack is impossible to override.

What would be the best practice here?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that *role vars (defined in role/vars/main.yml)* have a higher variable [precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) than *group vars*. There are two options to deal with this:

1. it should be possible to use the [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html) module to load the group_vars needed with a higher precedence
2. fork the role and alter it to your needs

Forking the role would be my preferred option.